# Passing props to functional React component in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, enums, react-redux

I'm converting a class-based React app to use React hooks with functional components, but I'm coming across an odd error when I try and pass props down to a child component.

There are two props I want to pass: `critterType` and `critter`.

`critterType` is an `enum` which is declared like this:

```
export enum critterType {
    bug,
    fish,
}
```

`critter` is an `ICritter` object with the following interface:

```
export interface ICritter {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    thumbnail: string;
    location: string;
    price: number;
    times: ITimeSpan[];
    northMonths: number[];
    southMonths: number[];
    silhouetteSize?: number;
}
```

(We don't need to worry about `ITimeSpan` for now.)

The `CritterEntry` compenent looks like this:

```
function CritterEntry(typeOfCritter: critterType, critter: ICritter) {
    const critterId = critter.id.toString();    

    const state = store.getState();

    let caughtSource: string[] = [];
    let donatedSource: string[] = [];

    switch(typeOfCritter) {
        case critterType.bug: {
            caughtSource = state.caughtCritters.bugs;
            donatedSource = state.donatedCritters.bugs;
            break;
        }
        case critterType.fish: {
            caughtSource = state.caughtCritters.fish;
            donatedSource = state.donatedCritters.fish;
        }
    }

    const caught = caughtSource.indexOf(critterId) > -1;
    const donated = donatedSource.indexOf(critterId) > -1;

    return (
        <li className={'critterEntry'}>
            <ul>
                <li>{critter.name}</li>
                <li>{critter.price} bells</li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li onClick={() => store.dispatch(catchCritter({id: critterId, critterType: typeOfCritter}))}>{caught ? 'Caught' : 'Not caught'}</li>
                <li onClick={() => store.dispatch(donateCritter({id: critterId, critterType: typeOfCritter}))}>{donated ? 'Donated' : 'Not donated'}</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    );
}

export default CritterEntry;
```

(Don't worry too much about `state` here, either; it's enough to know that it has a `caught` object and a `donated` object, both of which have two properties: one for `bugs` and one for `fish`, each of which is an array of strings.)

In the parent component, I'm looping through a list of `critter`s like so:

```
allBugs.map((critter:ICritter) => <CritterEntry typeOfCritter={critterType.bug} critter={critter} key={`all_bug_${critter.id}`} />)
```

The part that's totally stumping me is that the `allBugs.map` function is throwing an error:

```
Type '{ typeOfCritter: critterType; critter: ICritter; key: string; }' is not assignable to type '(IntrinsicAttributes & critterType.bug) | (IntrinsicAttributes & critterType.fish)'.
      Type '{ typeOfCritter: critterType; critter: ICritter; key: string; }' is not assignable to type 'critterType.fish'.
```

From all the documentation I've read, it seems like I should be able to pass the props sown to the `CritterEntry` component just as I used to in the class-based app, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

I'm probably missing something totally obvious here. Can anyone spot the error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first argument to the component `CritterEntry` should be an object which will be the props to that component. You should annotate the props as one object instead of passing them as separate arguments.

Try this,

```js
interface ICritterEntryProps {
   typeOfCritter: critterType;
   critter: ICritter;
}

function CritterEntry(props: React.PropsWithChildren<ICritterEntryProps>) {
   // access to typeOfcritter and critter by destructuring from props

   const { typeOfCritter, critter } = props;


   // rest of the component logic
}
```

Also there is a generic type `React.FC` that can help you when using arrow functions

```js
interface ICritterEntryProps {
   typeOfCritter: critterType;
   critter: ICritter;
}

const CritterEntry: React.FC<ICritterEntryProps> = ({ typeOfCritter, critter}) => {
   // component logic
}
```

The second argument to a functional component can be `ref` object and can be used when using `forwardRef` but that is not important here.